# Differentiability of $ |z|^{10} Re(z^2) $ without Cauchy-Riemann equations

Tags: complex-analysis

The Cauchy-Riemann equations are probably the most straightforward way to determine complex differentiability  of $ f(z) = |z|^{10}Re(z^2) $, but there's supposedly a good way to solve this without using them. However, I'm failing to see it.

Comment: Hint: purely real-valued non-constant functions cannot be complex-differentiable...

Comment: @paulgarrett that implicitly uses CR equations. No?

Comment: @OpenBall, that purely real-valued (non-constant) functions are not complex differentiable can certainly be done via the Cauchy-Riemann equations, which at least is more economical than actually applying the C-R equations to a complicated explicit formulaic object. But, also, for example, composing with (for example) the sine function, one would have a bounded entire (non-constant) function, contradicting Liouville's theorem. Also, for example, a purely real-valued (non-constant) function contradicts the open-mapping property of holomorphic functions. Lots of possibilities...